# Clean up question on this Q&A

Tags: discussion, contest, unanswered-questions

Other sites (for example, Ask Ubuntu) have occasionally had [question cleanup events](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1220/85695) in an attempt to clear out unanswered questions.

Basically, the AU mods made a kind of game where they selected candidate questions from the heap of unanswered and you were rewarded if you found the solution to them. I remember winning an AU t-shirt and a couple of Stack Exchange pens for example.

Could we do the same here?

Comment: Useful search: [answers:0 score:2 is:question closed:no](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=answers%3a0%20score%3a2%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3ano) ... change the score to whatever criteria you'd like.

Comment: Also, even after AU had those, we're still 11 points higher on answered questions :-)

Comment: We can definitely do this, but we generally try and do this (at least some of us) as time permits as just a basic event, no gamification.

Comment: We did do this [a while back](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/873/a-contest-to-cleanup-old-abandoned-questions) as a contest; we can look into some sort of event